# auto fill form without id tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i'm a newbie with tampermonkey and i want to auto fill a form but has no id ...i already tried some codes but doesnt work

source

```
<input type="text" name="user_email" class="form-control-input" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" autocomplete="off">
```

code already tested

```
  var mail = "test@gmail.com";
  document.getElementsByClassName('form-control-input').value = mail;
```

Comment: Change `class` to `id` or `querySelector` and that should work for you. If you notice, you are getting `ElementsByClassName` "elements" notice how it's plural? The gist of it is it's expecting to grab an array of elements but it's not getting that. When using `className`, you have to itirate the result and assign them values

Comment: if you found users answer useful, give the answer an upvote it helps both the user and future users who might run into the issue you just had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to use jQuery over pure javascript in tampermonkey because it gives me more control such as loading the script when the DOM is ready. i.e. wrap the function in a $(document).ready(function() ...

you can try this out (make sure to change the @match)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        <your site here>
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=undefined.
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mail = "test@gmail.com";
        $('[name=user_email]').val(mail);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `class` to `id` or `querySelector`. Using `getElementsByClassName()`will return a collection of NodeList. So think of an array in this instance. If you use `getElementsByClassName()` you're telling the DOM **"Hey I want to work on a number of things"** so in order to add that `string` value to **" these number of things"**, you need to go through them one by one and give them the `value` i.e you will need to loop through this NodeList and do what you want on **"these number of things"**.

**When to use getElementsByClassName**

In your case, since you're only working on one input, it's easier to select using `id` and go with that. If you have say 10 different `input` fields that you need to use a `prefill` for then use `getElementsByClassName()` but if you only have like 2 or 3 fields i recommend just giving each one a unique `id` and using that

```js
  var mail = "test@gmail.com";
  document.getElementById('form-control-input').value = mail
```

```html
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="form-control-input" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" autocomplete="off">
```